# docker stack with overlay network & name resolution

Tags: docker, docker-compose, service-discovery

I'm totally new to docker and started yesterday to do some tutorials. I want to build a small test application consisting of several different services (replicated and so on) that interact with each other and encountered a problem regarding 'service-discovery'. I started with the get-started tutorials on docker.com and at the moment i'm not really sure what's best practice in the world of docker to let the different containers in a network get to know each other...

As this is a rather vague 'problem description', i try to make this more precise. I want to use a few independent services (e.g. with stuff like postgre, mongodb, redis and rabbitmq...) together with a set of worker nodes to which work is assigned by a dedicated master node. Since it seems to be quite convenient, I wanted to use a docker-composer.yml file to define all my services and deploy them as a stack. 
Moreover, I created a custom network and since it seems not to be possible to attach a stacked service to a bridge network, I created an attachable overlay network.

To finally get to the point: even though the services are deployed correctly, their actual container-name is random and without using somekind of service registry I'm not able to resolve their addresses. 
A simple solution would be to use single containers with fixed container names - however this does not seem to be a best practice solution (even though it is actually just a docker-based DNS that is based on container names rather than domain names). Another problem are the randomly generated container names that contain underscores, and hence these names are not valid addresses that can be resolved...

best regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at something like [Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/)?  To quote from the home page:

> It groups containers that make up an application into logical units for easy management and discovery.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i just figured out that the solution is actually much simpler... one can simply use the service name specified in the composer file...